# How to vertically align text in a definition list?

Tags: html, css

I have a definition list. I want to vertically align the text in the middle of each dd.

```css
dl, dt, dd {
    margin:0;
}
dt {
    background: blue;
}
dd {
    min-height: 100px;
    background: gold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<dl> 
    <dt>Fruit</dt>
    <dd>Apple</dd>
    <dd>Banana</dd>
    <dd>Pear</dd>
</dl>
```

I've tried to do this using the table cell method - [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spjmyzx7/). But that has caused all of the dd's to output in one line when they should be on top of each other.

How can I get a stacked list, with the text vertically aligned in each gold coloured section?

Please note: **No flexfox** please, and text could be **multi-lined**.

Comment: Are you locked into the HTML hierarchy you have now or can that be changed?

Comment: I am locked into the HTML as it stands.

Comment: And is JavaScript or jQuery an option?

Comment: You want the text in each dd to be in the middle vertically, is that right?

Comment: Yes text in each dd should be vertically aligned.

Comment: Can you add an <span> in to each <dd>?

Comment: Yes I can add stuff inside the dd's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can add extra tags into the `<dd>`, here is the solution, so set each `<dd>` as `table` and each `<span>` inside as `table-cell`, then we can set the vertical alignment to it.

It works with multiple lines of text, see the following demo.

```css
dl, dt, dd {
    margin:0;
}
dl {
    width: 100px;
}
dt {
    background: crimson;
}
dd {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: gold;
}
dd span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<dl> 
    <dt>Fruit</dt>
    <dd><span>Apple</span></dd>
    <dd><span>Banana, I love bananas.</span></dd>
    <dd><span>Pear</span></dd>
</dl>
```